# Launching a detached process with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm currently trying to understand the `subprocess.run()` api and to do this my goal is to create a detached subprocess that will source another python env, log it's python executable path and exit properly.

Right now, I have this main function that throws an NamedError. I'd really like to rely on the `run` api but I don't know how to pass the `creationflags` and even if it's the good way to achieve my goal.

Edit : the error is of course because I didn't import the constants. My question was mainly : how to create such a subprocess with `subprocess.run()` and without being able to use `DETACHED_PROCESS` nor `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

```py
import subprocess
import logging
import shlex
import sys

# VENV is virtual env on the model /my/venv/path/bin
def main() -> None:
    python_path = sys.executable
    logger.debug("Base python executable : %(python_path)s")
    tokens = shlex.split(
        f"source {VENV} && python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)'"
    )
    proc = subprocess.run(
        tokens,
        shell=True,
        text=True,
        capture_output=True,
        creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
    )

    logger.debug(
        "In the detached subprocess, the python exec is: %(proc.stdout)s"
    )
```

The error :

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in main
    creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
NameError: name 'DETACHED_PROCESS' is not defined
```

Comment: You did not import the constants: `creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` or `from subprocess import DETACHED_PROCESS,CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`

Answer (score 1):

`DETACHED_PROCESS` is in the subprocess namespace and it is only there on Windows systems: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/subprocess.py#L85

```
subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
```